# RoR / Ruby delete nil elements from nested array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, recursion, null

To split an array into two equal pieces I would do this,

```
>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>> a.in_groups_of( (a.size/2.0).ceil ) if a.size > 0
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, nil]]
```

Now I've got a nested array that contains nil elements if the size of the array is odd. How can I remove the nil elements from the nested arrays? I want to do something like,

```
a.compact
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work, ruby only removes nil elements on the first level and not recursively. Does ruby provide any nice solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With Ruby 1.8.7 and later you can do the following:

```
a.each &:compact!
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

With Ruby 1.8.6, you have do do this the long way:

```
a.each {|s| s.compact!}
```

Both of these will modify the contents of `a`. If you want to return a new array and leave the original alone, you can use `collect` instead of `each`:

```
# 1.8.7+:
a.collect &:compact

# 1.8.6:
a.collect {|s| s.compact}
```

Comment: I thought the & syntax was introduced in 1.8.7

Comment: @EmFi Good point - I was forgetting 1.8.7. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: You can also use `a.map(&:compact)`

Answer (score 8):

If you were to use the [`in_groups_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Grouping.html#M001216) you can pass it `false` as the second argument and it will not fill in the "blanks" with `nil`, but truly nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you want to permanently change *a*

```
a.map do |e|
  e.compact
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr_mixed=['hello', 2222, 'world', nil, [1, 2, 5, 'hi', nil],[1, 2, 3], [4,   5, nil]]

def compact_nested(array)
   arr2=[]
   array.each { |x|
   element = x.class==Array ? x.compact : x
   arr2<<element
   }
   arr2
end

p compact_nested(arr_mixed).compact #=>["hello", 2222, "world", [1, 2, 5, "hi"], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
p arr_mixed #=>["hello", 2222, "world", nil, [1, 2, 5, "hi", nil], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, nil]]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
a.each {|subarray| subarray.compact!}
a.compact!
```

Should work....

Comment: Probably not worth necro-posting, but this two lines should be in opposite order. If we assume that `a` has `nil`s then we should *`compact` it first*, otherwise we will get nil-errors inside the block.